# How to get Bootstrap Nav-Pills Tab links AND Page links to work simultaneously

Tags: bootstrap-4, href, nav-pills

I'm using Bootstrap Nav-Pills and within them I need to use links that both point to different tabs/pills on the same page, and point to different pages (some with anchor tags) on the same site.

Originally, the links to other pages worked fine, but I needed to add JS (which I don't know -- thank you, Stack Overflow for the code) to get the links to other tabs/pills working.  Now that the JS is added (which works great on getting the tab/pill links working), the links to the other pages no longer work.

Example: In the "GENERAL INFORMATION" section below, the "categories" tab/pill link (#tab-4) needs the JS at the bottom of the code to work, but that same code disables the "email our office" (contact.htm#email) link.

```
<body>
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills"> 
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">General</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Age Groups</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#tab-3" data-toggle="tab">Divisions</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#tab-4" data-toggle="tab">Categories</a></li>  
      <li class=""><a href="#tab-5" data-toggle="tab">Entry Fees</a></li>  
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane active">
        <h2>GENERAL INFORMATION</h2>
        <p>Contestants may enter as many <a href="#tab-4">categories</a> as desired but each routine must be different.</p>
        <p><i>If you have any questions, please <a href="contact.htm#email">email our office</a>.</i></p>
      </div>
      <div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane">          
        <h2>AGE GROUPS</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane">          
        <h2>DIVISIONS</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="tab-4" class="tab-pane">          
        <h2>CATEGORIES</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="tab-5" class="tab-pane">          
        <h2>ENTRY FEES</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#tabs a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').tab('show');
    })
  });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      var hash = window.location.hash;
      // do some validation on the hash here
      hash && $('ul.nav a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
  });
  </script>

</body>
```

I'm still searching for solutions -- I'm admittedly a JS newbee.  While I continue my search, if any JS pros how to update the existing JS so that I can link both to tabs/pills and other pages, it will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to add #email in your url?

Comment: Adding #email is a nice-to-have, but not required.  Thanks!

Comment: In the first script, would an If-Else statement work (if href contains "htm" null, if not execute script)?  I tried playing with the script myself, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you.

```
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane active">
    <h2>GENERAL INFORMATION</h2>
    <p>Contestants may enter as many <a href="#tab-4">categories</a> as desired...</p>
    <p><i>If... please <a class="cemail" href="#email">email our office</a>.</i></p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".cemail").click(function(e) {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: That helps, but it is pointing me to the same page -- contact.htm is a different page and I lost that in row 4 of your update.  I'm still playing with it... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  Thanks Mr. Perfectionist for sparking what I needed to get there.

I needed to change the first script so that it can be used as a class.  Specifically:
(1) Change: 
    '#tabs a' to '.tabsclick'
(2) Add:
    class="tabsclick" to the categories link in the body